# ERROR #98123 WEBPACK Generating development JavaScript bundle failed on `gatsby develop`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, gatsby

I ran the following commands to create a new gatsby starter blog:

`gatsby new blog https://github.com/alxshelepenok/gatsby-starter-lumen`

`cd blog`

`gatsby develop`

But during `gatsby develop`, I'm getting a lot of errors named `ERROR #98123 WEBPACK` saying-  **Generating development JavaScript bundle failed**.

I've been trying for so long and deleted and installed the repo again and again, and also deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then `npm install` but getting the same error again. Help me out!

For details, [here is the complete list of errors I am getting](https://gist.github.com/toolarmy/f1a1585feaabc0eac086681915d59e68) (it's a bit long):

Packages:

```
 node v10.19.0
 npm 6.14.4
 OS: Ubunut 20.04LTS
```

````
    "gatsby": "^2.31.1",
    "gatsby-cli": "^2.18.0",
    "gatsby-link": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "^2.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-flow": "^1.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-gtag": "^2.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^4.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-optimize-svgs": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.13.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.11.0",
    "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.9.0",
    "gatsby-remark-external-links": "0.0.4",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.10.0",
    "gatsby-remark-katex": "^3.9.0",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^3.12.0",
    "gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^2.9.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.15.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.11.0",
    ```
````

Answer (score 6):

My problem was similar.  I installed a new Gatsby site, no plugins, and when making simple HTML changes, then previewing the DEVELOP site and refreshing, every time I would see these webpack errors that were cryptic at best.

This fixed everything:

1. Stop server (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
2. Run `gatsby clean`
3. Delete node_modules folder
4. Delete *package-lock.json* file
5. Install Yarn if it isn't installed already (`npm install -g yarn`)
6. Run yarn install (`yarn install`)
7. Restart your server and test (`gatsby develop`)

Credit goes to [Ferran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65970921/error-98123-webpack-generating-development-javascript-bundle-failed-on-gatsby/65971584#65971584).

Comment: delete package-lock.json file and not just node_modules folder helped me out, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The issues are quite self-explanatory:

```
/home/myPC/Documents/blog/src/components/Feed/Feed.js
  4:13  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token {
✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

File: src/components/Feed/Feed.js

/home/myPC/Documents/blog/src/components/Icon/Icon.js
  5:6  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token Props

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

File: src/components/Icon/Icon.js
```

And so on...

As you can see in [their repository](https://github.com/alxshelepenok/gatsby-starter-lumen/blob/master/yarn.lock), you must use yarn instead of npm since the dependencies are lock using `yarn.lock` file.

So, remove your `node_modules`, your `cache` folder and run `yarn install`(you may need to install it before).

Comment: Where is the cache folder?

Comment: Just run `gatsby clean`, it's a built-in method for deleting the cache folder (it's in the root of the folder, named `.cache`)

Comment: Have you removed the package-lock.json too?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because there was an apostrophe and/or space in my windows username.
Switching to another user solved the problem.
If your error includes the following this might be your problem too.

```
./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed node modules , cache folder and public folder . After that I simply run

```
npm i 
gatsby clean && gatsby build
```

My issue was fixed after that